# Should a class diagram for an aspnet MVC Application include model classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have problem in making class diagram for asp.net mvc. since in mvc application i have model classes and controller classes, so m confused that class diagram should include model classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should include the model classes.